# Sync two web views

Tags: swift, desktop-application

I have a need to sync two web views, so that anything that happens in one web view happens simultaneously in the other.

I have tried various ways, without success, and the more I try the more convoluted and likely bug ridden this is getting.

I feel there maybe a very simple way to do this, but can not figure it out.
One of the things that I note is not allowed is having the same NSTextField as the "takeStringURLFrom"

```
override func controlTextDidEndEditing(obj: NSNotification) {
    webViewLeft.takeStringURLFrom(hiddenTextField)
    webViewRight.takeStringURLFrom(urlField)
}

override func webView(sender: WebView!, didCommitLoadForFrame frame: WebFrame!) {
    if frame == sender.mainFrame {
            urlField.stringValue = sender.mainFrameURL
            hiddenTextField.stringValue = sender.mainFrameURL
            webViewRight.takeStringURLFrom(urlField)
            webViewLeft.takeStringURLFrom(hiddenTextField)
            printLn("realised just creating an infinite loop here")
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain, what you mean by synchronization in this context. I.e. is it also for user interactions? And *what* did you try so far?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to sync everything between the two web views. So user interactions as well as the two views sharing the takeStringURLFrom from a single NSTextField. I tried using 2 NSTextFields bound together from a var in the app delegate which takes care of that aspect, but if i then try and call takeStringURLFrom for each web view in the web view delegate (the app delegate) inside didCommitLoadForFrame it breaks.

Comment: updated code sample above

Answer (score 0):

I don't like this but it appears to work as needed. I think it needs some refinement. Using a hidden text field to mimic the url for the second web view and tie each web view to there respective text fields via the web view's referenced action "takeStringUrlFrom"

```
override func webView(sender: WebView!, didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame frame: WebFrame!) {
    if frame == sender.mainFrame {
        urlField.stringValue = sender.mainFrameURL
        hiddenTextField.stringValue = sender.mainFrameURL
        window.makeFirstResponder(nil)
        window.makeFirstResponder(hiddenTextField)
        window.makeFirstResponder(nil)
        window.makeFirstResponder(urlField)
        window.makeFirstResponder(nil)
    }
}
```